# Microphone dosen't work

Tags: microphone

The problem is that when using simple screen recorder the microphone works, but when in any other program the microphone doesn't work like in Discord, Browser even pavucontrol. The microphone worked in windows 10 and failed like this in kubuntu and linux mint.

Mine laptop is not being manufactured anymore.